# does nulling a System.Threading.Timer stop it?

Tags: c#

If I have an active [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(VS.90).aspx) and I set it to null, is it stopped?

I realize that it is more proper to call  `.Dispose()` but I would like an answer to the question as written.

```
public class Foo
{
   private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
   public Foo()
   {
      // initialize timer
   }

   public void KillTimer()
   {
      _timer=null;
   }
}
```

---

#### Update:

After much back and forth about whether setting a single reference to a System.Threading.Timer to null will indeed result stopping it have shown that

1. there are no lingering references, e.g. events list, as a threading timer takes a sinlge callback and does not expose events.
2. that ***if*** GC collects, the finalizer will indeed dispose the TimerBase and stop the timer.

spike

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace SO_3597276
{
    class Program
    {
        private static System.Threading.Timer _timer;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _timer = new Timer((s) => Console.WriteLine("fired"), null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
            _timer = null;
            GC.Collect();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The timer callback is not called. Remove `GC.Collect()` and the callback is called.

Thanks all.

Comment: Why do you think there are no more references to the Timer just because you set your variable to null?  Presumably the Timer has been added to some system event queue for the purpose of noticing when it is time for the Timer to fire.  Do you know if that event queue uses a WeakReference to refer to the Timer? (WeakReference is a Java concept: I don't know whether .NET has a similar concept)

Comment: @adrian - yes, .net has System.WeakReference. Regarding your question: the code above proves that there are no more references, otherwise the timer would fire 1 second into the readkey block. On a more technical note, when creating the timer, the callback is ultimately fed to `private extern void AddTimerNative`. Apparently what would normally be a .net delegate is handled in unmanaged code and not treated as a reference. I don't pretend to understand exactly what is happening there, but it makes sense in correlation with the code above. I hope will be some more discussion of this.

Comment: @adrian - and as blindly throw darts at the problem, it occurs to me that the salient issue is that it is a function pointer that is being passed around as opposed to a delegate, thus no reference to the timer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Setting it to null, removes any references to it, and relies on the garbage collector to dispose of it.

If the timer went off before the GC got to it, it would trigger the event.

Comment: I like it, as it 1) agrees with what I supposed to be the case and 2) because it directly addresses the question, which implies that there is a single reference, and indeed, setting that to null will remove any references to it. I would have liked to see 'removes the sole reference' or some such, but close enough for gubment work. The other answers, while correct and informative, miss the point just slightly while still supporting your answer. I am inclined to accept this answer.

Answer (score 11):

Why would it?

Consider:

```
  System.Threading.Timer t = ...;
  System.Threading.Timer q = t;
  q = null; // Should this stop it as well?
```

Setting to null is something you do to a variable, not something you do to an object. The Timer has no way of knowing you set a particular variable to null, and cannot take action on the basis of that.

EDIT:

To address the edit, even in the case of having a sole reference, it is not guaranteed that the Timer will be stopped, as it is possible the GC may not run after the reference has been set to null. This is not entirely unlikely either, the Microsoft .NET implementation uses a generational collector and a static field will likely survive a nursery collection and be promoted to an older generation. If your program has a relatively stable memory profile there may never be a collection of the older generations (and by extension the finalizer will not run until the end of the program).

Comment: The GC cleans up unreferenced objects automatically, so setting it to null "could" have an effect.

Comment: @Russell if the collector runs, and if that was the only reference to the timer. There's not a direct cause and effect relationship between setting a variable to null and stopping a timer.

Comment: The cause/effect is "if the timer has no more references", then the GC will dispose of it.

Comment: Only if the GC runs. It's perfectly possible to have a program that never has a collection, nor does setting a variable to null guarantee that all references to an object are gone.

Comment: @Russell: no, the GC will collect it. That will only `Dispose` it if it has a finalizer and the finalizer calls `Dispose`.

Comment: Even if the GC runs, it may not dispose the object at that time.  It will mark it for the finalizer thread to dispose it on next execution

Comment: "A correctly written program cannot rely on the side-effects of a finalizer." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx

Comment: I guess I could have been more precise in the question, but the inference is that I have a single reference, not that I have multiple references. The results of setting a single reference to null are distinctly different that those of setting one of multiple references to null. no?

Comment: @josh - i think you sum it up quite nicely.

Comment: @codepoet: no, setting a reference to null does not help. Stop using the reference, and you'll have the same effect one statement earlier.

Comment: @John - given the contrived (no offense) example, you are correct, but consider a more likely scenario in which the timer is declared in a wider scope, say a field, perhaps static, with one reference, the field, setting it to null will qualify it for GC, no? If I take out another reference to the field by assigning another variable to it (q in the above example) and set that to null, there is no effect. That is what I am getting at.

Comment: If your question is whether or not the finalizer will stop the timer, I would suggest grabbing Reflector and checking out the disassembly for both the .NET Framework and Silverlight. Having said that, as others have tried to imply - this only tells you whether or not it MIGHT happen since you can't count on finalizers.

Comment: @codepoet you could edit/ask a new question to be more precise, but I think the answer is still the same, in so far as if the GC never runs, the finalizer never runs no matter the lack of references to the Timer. And as @JohnSaunders points out, if the runtime figures out you never use the timer again anyway, setting it to null is superfluous.

Comment: @josh - yes, reflector is a way to go. the question came up while dealing with some old bad code (mine) and it sure sounded like a good SO question and has resulted in enough discussion to make the answer quite clear: a single reference set to null *may* get stopped by GC but relying on a finalizer is just bad code. Which is as I suspected.

Comment: @code: you say there are events, right? Nulling the field won't do anything about the delegate instances in the event list, which all hold a reference to the object. Really, the answer is: don't do that, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @John - AHHHHHH - the handlers. That is what I am disregarding. So slaks is correct that there are references other than the field. Thanks for taking the time to explain. And, yeah, I know 'don't do that' - this question was prompted by some old bad code of mine that reared it's ugly head and the problem was obvious, just wanted to put it out here and get some real live experts talking about it to help cement the issue in my noggin. Thanks again to all.

Comment: @John on second thought, is not the delegate list a member of the timer, thus nulled with it?

Comment: @code: when you set the field to null, all you are doing is making the field not reference the timer. You do not affect the timer in any way.

Comment: @john - man, you have some kind of patience. hard to believe that i keep not understanding that. thanks.

Comment: @john, actually I mispoke yet again. A threading timer takes a callback and does not expose events. so nulling a single reference and then picking it up with GC does indeed prevent firing. I have updated question with a spike. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

I know you're asking about the `System.Threading.Timer` class, but I want to point out something rather important.

The answers provided so far are good. [Logan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597276/does-nulling-a-system-threading-timer-stop-it/3597285#3597285) and [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597276/does-nulling-a-system-threading-timer-stop-it/3597282#3597282) are right that setting any variable to `null` has no direct effect on the object to which the variable was previously assigned. [Russell is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597276/does-nulling-a-system-threading-timer-stop-it/3597286#3597286) that when the garbage collector *does* eventually dispose of the timer, however, it *will* stop.

SLaks indicated that after setting a timer reference to `null`, there may be lingering references. In the simple example of one `System.Threading.Timer` reference, this is not the case.

**But**, if you have, for example, a [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), and you handle its `Elapsed` event, then setting it to `null` **will** leave a reference and the timer **will** continue to run forever.

So consider this code for example:

```
var t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000.0);
t.AutoReset = true;
t.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

Console.Write("Press Enter to start the timer.");
Console.ReadLine();
t.Start();

Console.Write("Press Enter to set t to null.");
Console.ReadLine();

// This will not stop the timer. It actually does nothing at all to the timer
// to which t has been assigned.
t = null;

Console.Write("Press Enter again to perform a garbage collection.");
Console.ReadLine();

// This STILL will not stop the timer, as t was not the only reference to it
// (we created a new one when we added a handler to the Elapsed event).
GC.Collect();

Console.Write("t is null and garbage has been collected. Press Enter to quit.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

In the example above, as there is code holding onto a reference to `t` in order to handle its `Elapsed` event, the timer will never stop.

Again, I realize this is not the class you asked about; I only bring this up to point out that it is not always obvious whether in fact you do or do not have any more references to a given object.

---

**UPDATE**: It seems some confusion has sprung up on the topic of whether the statement I made above is equally true of a `System.Threading.Timer` object; **it is not**. To verify this, consider the following modification of the above code:

```
Console.Write("Press Enter to start the timer.");
Console.ReadLine();

var t = new System.Threading.Timer(
    state => { Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now); },
    null,
    0,
    1000
);

Console.Write("Press Enter to set t to null.");
Console.ReadLine();

// This will not stop the timer. It actually does nothing at all to the timer
// to which t has been assigned. HOWEVER, if/when the GC comes around to collect
// garbage, it will see that said timer has no active references; and so it will
// collect (and therefore finalize) it.
t = null;

Console.Write("Press Enter again to perform a garbage collection.");
Console.ReadLine();

// This WILL cause the timer to stop, as there is code in the type's
// finalizer to stop it.
GC.Collect();

Console.Write("t is null and garbage has been collected. Press Enter to quit.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Here's why it doesn't work for `System.Timers.Timer` (or any type that has events, actually)**:

The answer is very easy to miss when we've defined our event handler like this:

```
t.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

What if I defined my handler like this instead?

```
t.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(sender.GetType());
```

Oh right! That `sender` argument that nobody ever pays any attention to!

The event-handling infrastructure provided by .NET requires that objects *handling* events maintain references to objects *raising* events. Otherwise, the contract provided by the very signature of the `EventHandler` delegate and all its cousins would be violated.

The moral of this story is: as soon as you add a handler to an event, you have created a new reference to an object. The only way to allow that object to be garbage collected after this point is to remove the handler -- but this may be quite difficult if you've set the only other reference to said object to `null` (this is one of the very few examples of a case where a .NET program may have a "memory leak").

Comment: Very good point. There's also the Windows Forms Timer and WPF DispatcherTimer and I would not be surprised if they are tracked by internal references too.

Comment: dan, john brought up a good point that seems to overlap both slaks answer and this one.. the handler delegates that are in the events list. not entirely clear that this list is not a member of the timer and thus nulled with it.

Comment: never mind. for some reason i keep not understanding that nulling the reference does not null the object. so there are lingering references even with a System.Threading.Timer

Comment: @code poet: There are not lingering references with `System.Threading.Timer` if you only had one reference to it. If you set that reference to `null`, then there are no more active references, and when the timer is garbage collected (and therefore finalized) it will indeed stop. The reason `System.Timers.Timer` is different is that once you have attached a handler to its `Elapsed` **event**, right away there is a new reference to the timer, and it will never be garbage collected. I will update my answer to explain this hopefully more clearly.

Comment: @dan - you are right. this back and forth is making me dizzy. I went ahead and spiked the proof. thanks for prompting me.

Comment: thanks dan. Great answer. I have awarded (unawarded and re-awarded ;-)) the check but I hope your answer gets the attention it deserves. our proofs are functionally equivalent but as usual you bring an elegance that is not unnoticed. cheers

Comment: so I guess, in the case of a threading timer, we are dealing with a pointer as opposed to a delegate which is the crux of the difference in behavior. Is that about right?

Comment: "handling events maintain references to objects raising events" this is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not stop.

Setting a variable to `null` does not directly have any side-effects such as stopping a timer.  (Unless it's a property)

<strike>Since the timer has other references, the GC will not collect it, and it will never stop.</strike>

Comment: hey slaks. what other references are we talking about?

Comment: @kbrimington: The working example is not realistic because in this app the garbage collector may never run. Add a `GC.Collect` line and you will see that *then* the timer stops. So it isn't really accurate to say "it will never stop." It just may not (in fact, almost certainly *will* not) stop in any sort of deterministic way right after been set to `null`.

Comment: @kbrimington - you should probably add the code example as your own answer. I don't know that it's really respectful to edit a 75k+'ers answer to add your own code. For example, if it had mistakes or didn't make SLaks' point, it would reflect on him as most people aren't going to look through the history.

Comment: @Josh - Fair enough. I had hoped only to help.